# Apply CSS style attributes to @Html.TextBox

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an MVC application.

I have the following line of code:

```
@Lines.Html.TextBox(p => p.Dscription)
```

How can apply my own style to this text box? i.e. change the width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add another param to the helper:

```
@Lines.Html.TextBox(p => p.Dscription, new {@class="clasecss", more properties})
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can just append a generic object as the second parameter which contains the appropriate attributes ::

```
@Lines.Html.TextBox(p => p.Description, new { @class = "className", @style = "width: 200px" }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an overload of (Textbox) html helper:

```
@Lines.Html.TextBox(p => p.Dscription, null, new { @class = "css-class" })
```